# Store Flyway metadata table externally

Tags: flyway, amazon-athena

So just exploring the possibility of using flyway to maintain my DDL statements against Amazon Athena using Athena provided JDBC driver, Athena supports only CREATE statements (hive DDL) and no INSERTS.

So if database metadata table is the only one that flyway creates and updates, Is there anyway I can externalize the creating, storing into a totally different database ?

Comment: Hi @Sathyakumar: Did you resolved this ?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: I'm curious to know, why do you want to store the flyway metadata table outside the target database. As far as i understand, flyway uses the details stored in the metadata table 'flyway_schema_history' from the target DB to compare and apply only the new changes when you run/execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible in flyway, as the schema history is read from/written to the database defined by the current jdbc connection. You can see this for yourself in the [JDBCTableSchemaHistory](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/schemahistory/JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java) file.

If you wish to add this support, you could create a pull request on the repo, or just add an issue detailing exactly what you want the behaviour to be.